# NAudio float data stream

Tags: c#, audio, audio-streaming, naudio

I want to use NAudio for streaming float audio data. I figured out, that you can use a IWaveProvider like this:

```
    public abstract class WaveProviderFloat : IWaveProvider
    {
        private WaveFormat m_WaveFormat;

        protected WaveProviderFloat()
        {
            SetWaveFormat(48000, 2);
        }

        protected WaveProviderFloat(int aSampleRate, int aChannels)
        {
            SetWaveFormat(aSampleRate, aChannels);
        }

        public void SetWaveFormat(int aSampleRate, int aChannels)
        {
            this.m_WaveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(aSampleRate, aChannels);
        }

        public int Read(byte[] aBuffer, int aOffset, int aCount)
        {
            WaveBuffer waveBuffer = new WaveBuffer(aBuffer);
            int samplesRequired = aCount / 4;
            int samplesRead = Read(waveBuffer.FloatBuffer, aOffset / 4, samplesRequired);
            return samplesRead * 4;
        }

        public abstract int Read(float[] aBuffer, int aOffset, int aSampleCount);

        public WaveFormat WaveFormat => m_WaveFormat;
    }
```

And in your program you can init it like this:

```
        var testFloatProvider = new TestFloatProvider();
        var waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(testFloatProvider);
        waveOut.Play();
```

Is this correct so far? I have only one problem with the read-block where always a new WaveBuffer is created:

```
WaveBuffer waveBuffer = new WaveBuffer(aBuffer);
```

I don´t fully understand why I have to do it this way. What about the performance and garbage collection here? Thanks for answers.

Comment: I think you're fine.  Read [the WaveBuffer source](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveBuffer.cs) to see how `new WaveBuffer(aBuffer)` actually calls `BindTo(aBuffer)` and the different formats are aliased (to reinterpret the same memory) using `FieldOffset(8)`

Comment: I'd also be inclined not to split up the channel pairs.  (never write out a Left without a matching Right).  If they give you a buffer size that was divisible by 4 but not divisible by 8, (e.g. 12) that would leave you in a weird state and a risk of getting accidentally stereo swapped.

Comment: OK, thanks, I figured out, that I can use the ISampleProvider interface. It´s easier using this. I just wonder, with which bit depth the audio file is sent to the sound card for the playback when I use the IeeeFloatWaveFormat. Can I set the bit depth to i.e. 8 bit with IeeeFloatWaveFormat? Where can I change this?